# code compiles on visual studio 2015 but failing on 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, system.xml

I have this method in a class

```
public static DataTable ConvertCellSetToDataTable(CellSet cellSet)
{
    return new DataTable();
}
```

I have `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient` in my packages.config as a nuget package and I DON'T have System.Xml as a project reference.

```
  <package id="Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient" version="12.0.2000.8" targetFramework="net452" />
```

This project fails to compile with Visual Studio 2013 Pro but the same solution file complies in Visual Stuido 2015 Pro on the same machine.

Error message from VS2013 as below:

`error CS0012: The type 'System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.`

I'm OK with this failure but why does it compile with Visual Studio 2015? What's new here?

Gist with all my files here:

https://gist.github.com/atwayne/ad8fdc06ee831626361609cfb5935638

Comment: Roslyn is new.  The C# compiler, somewhere around version 4.5, got a lot more strict about wanting to know types that are *indirectly* referenced.  Some kind of method overloading issue, a detail that the C# language specification does not mention.

Comment: did you try `using System.Xml;`?

Comment: That's what I meant.  The *old* version (4.5) got a lot more strict.

Comment: @Stan no I don't have that using statement in my class, adding it won't fix the error

Comment: What .NET version are you targeting with VS2013?  There was a framework versioning bug in 4.5.2 that caused errors with the same message you are seeing: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2971005.  The fix is to install  Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack.

Comment: The *using* statement does not help, you have to keep the compiler happy by adding the reference to the project's References node.  Keep in mind that System.Xml is normally always included so not exactly anything to fret about.

Comment: @RandyLevy I was targeting 4.5.2 but I got the same error for 4.5.0 as well.

Comment: @HansPassant Yep I'm ok with the failure as I said but I am wondering why it's not showing up in vs2015

Comment: Also an empty Unit Test project don't have System.xml as refrence ;( that's why I got this

Comment: The Roslyn project was also used to fix known bugs in the C# compiler.

Comment: So you tried adding `using System.Xml.Serialization`, not just `using System.Xml`, and that didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while, I am quoting comment from @Hans Passant as an answer:

> Roslyn is new. The C# compiler, somewhere around version 4.5, got a
>   lot more strict about wanting to know types that are indirectly
>   referenced. Some kind of method overloading issue, a detail that the
>   C# language specification does not mention.